# Scala : Understanding Future.recover

Tags: scala, future

I am playing around with `Future.recover` (through  a scala sheet in intelJ if it has any importance)

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def get():Future[Int] = {
  throw new ClassCastException
}

val n = get().map{
  x => x + 1

}.recover{
  case e: Throwable => print("we recovered")
    0
}

n.map(print(_)) // not getting here
```

I was expecting `0` to be printed. However, this what I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
    at #worksheet#.get(test.sc:5)
    at #worksheet#.n$lzycompute(test.sc:8)
    at #worksheet#.n(test.sc:8)
    at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$n(test.sc:8)
    at A$A76$.main(test.sc:32)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(test.sc)
```

Why is my `recover` not working. am I using it incorrectly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `get` function doesn't return a `Future`. It just immediately throws the `ClassCastException`. You need to create the `Future` somewhere.

Change your `get` function to this:

```
def get(): Future[Int] = Future {
    throw new ClassCastException
}
```

Comment: I see, but isn't get.map() resulting in a future containing an exception?  and so it should trigger the partial function in the recover combinator ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi No. `get` simply throws an exception, and everything crashes. It's like defining `def foo: Int = { throw new Error }` and then invoking `foo`: it just crashes, period. Everything after this point (`Future`, `recover`, `Throwable`, `map` etc.) is simply irrelevant, because your program has already exited.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I see. the fact that function is a supposed to be a future doesn't mean the exception is inside a Future.

Thank you !!!

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi That's right. `throw new ClassCastException` is an expression of type `Nothing` (bottom type), which is a subtype of `Future`. So, your `get` returns `Nothing` (crashes), it never constructs an actual instance of `Future` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
Future.failed(new ClassCastException)
```

The signature is:

```
def failed[T](exception: Throwable): scala.concurrent.Future[T]
```